# Is it possible to replace words that are not in comments in SQL Server Management Studio 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, ssms-2014

I know that in SQL Server Management Studio 2014 using Ctrl + H allows me to replace one word with another.

I have a database script (creation of tables, procedures, views, etc.) that are approximately 150000 lines of code, in this script I have added some extra comments that contain a word that I DO NOT want to remove from comments but I want to remove T-SQL code, for example:

```
-- Comment [SuperSec].[dbo].[tableA]

SELECT X.*
FROM [SuperSec].[dbo].[tableA] X
WHERE X.Id = '0';
```

I want it to look like this:

```
-- Comment [SuperSec].[dbo].[tableA]

SELECT X.*
FROM [dbo].[tableA] X
WHERE X.Id = '0';
```

Is it possible to do this using Regex or something similar?

**UPDATE:**

I did not say this at the beginning but this word corresponds to the name of the database, therefore it is referenced in many parts, not only in a FROM, also in a function, an EXEC of a procedure, a subquery, part of a SELECT , in many places.

Thanks :)

Comment: I would think a regex replace could do it.   Have you tried?

Comment: You can replace `FROM [SuperSec].` with `FROM `.

Comment: @Tab Alleman I'm not good with regex, but I'm searching the internet, so far nothing works

Comment: That does assume there there won't be `JOIN [SuperSec]...` anywhere in the OP's data, @GordonLinoff.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff It is referenced in a FROM, worse also in EXEC, in subqueries, WHERE, UPDATE, etc. Should I apply your solution with all these possibilities? I was curious if there was a way to do it faster.

Comment: I don't think SSMS is the best tool for this. If you had Notepad++ (for example) then you could probably use regex search/ replace to do what you need.  Here's an example of how to ignore comments (not a SQL example, but it should be easy enough to adapt it?): https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14118/search-text-in-source-code-excluding-comments

Comment: SSMS supports REGEX replacement, @RichardHansell

Comment: @Larnu, agreed, but prior to SSMS 2017 it wasn't regular regular expressions, it was non-standard REGEX, which is a bit of a weird choice (and one I'm glad they revisited).  OP is on SSMS 2014.

Comment: Considering that SSMS (2017) is free, I don't see a reason why the OP doesn't upgrade though, @RichardHansell :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to achieve that is to do that programmatically:

0) Put all your code to some NVARCHAR(MAX) column

1) (*see below comment) Find all pieces of commented code and replace your word ("[SuperSec].") with some unique tag like #$UNIQUETAG$#

2) Then replace your word ("[SuperSec].") with empty string in all remaining code

3) Finally, replace #$UNIQUETAG$# back with your initial word ("[SuperSec].")

So the only problem is Step 1 - to find the commented code. If all the comments  follow "-- ..." format and there are no "/* ... */" comments, it's not difficult to find it - it is anything between "--" and end of line (CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))

If you don't want to do programming... there are some solutions that you can adapt, e.g. [Remove all comments from a text in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47082399/remove-all-comments-from-a-text-in-t-sql) which finds and removes all comments. You just need to change its logic so instead of removing comments, it replaces your word in a comment with unique tag.